# How to track location using GPS for jQuery mobile app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I am developing a jQuery mobile app. I need to track the user's location (city address).

```
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else {
        x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position)
{
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

This gives only latitude and longitude. I don't need lat or long or maps. I need to get only the city address. What must I do to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it using [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding), this returns JSON. Use the URL this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false
```

Get the JSON like explained here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/